# Clarification in the terms of log-likelihood expression

Tags: self-study, matlab, terminology, kalman-filter, likelihood

I am trying to implement Eq(7) given below from [Parameter estimation for Linear dynamical system](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5997.)

[image: ll]
where Q is a 2 by 2 covariance matrix of the process noise. The model is `x` which is a 2 by T dimensional and observation vector is 1 by T dimensional for a state space model:

The state space model :

```
x(t+1) = Ax(t) + u(t)

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t)

w(t) = N(0,Q)

v(t) = N(0,R)
```

The answer should be a scalar negative value. On breaking up the equation, till the first three terms I am getting a scalar negative value. But as soon as I include the fourth term `(T-1)/2 log (abs(Q))` the value of the log-likelihood becomes a matrix with positive values in the diagonal and off-diagonal elements being infinity. Is my understanding of the notation incorrect? Is `| .|` not absolute but the determinant of  Q? Same for `V_1` and `R`?
Thank you for help.

UPDATE: Based on the answer, For the second expression: - 0.5*T*log(det(R)) the answer is coming : -0.5*T*log(0.0100) which becomes positive. How do I mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the determinant. The likelihoods in the first two expression look like multivariate normals. Look up

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

under properties, non-degenerate case they specify that $|\Sigma|$ is the determinant

Comment: Please see the update in my Question. I implemented the determinant which although gives a scalar for the likelihood, but it is a positive value instead of negative. Due to this answer which is a large positive number, the entire value of likelihood is becoming positive. Please help.

Comment: A likelihood *has* to be positive, because it is proportional to a probability. If you mean the *log* likelihood, its sign could be either positive or negative.

Comment: Adding to what @whuber mentions noting that (1) the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite and (2) the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues the determinant is necessarily positive.

Comment: @Sid:I ran the Kalman filter toolbox by Kevin Murphy. The log-likelihood is negative and it starts from a highly negative number slowly converging to a smaller negative number. From that point of view, the value of the log-likelihood expression must be negative because my implementation does not converge. I wrote my own implementation since it is very difficult to understand the mechanism otherwise. Will it be possible to go through my code? There is no run time error but I cannot figure out what is the problem. I will upload my code if you have time to go through it, please.

Comment: The LOG likelihood can absolutely be negative. The likelihood cannot be negative. The Kalman filter is providing a reasonable probabilistic result. What makes you believe the Kalman filter is not converging? By the sound of things it is converging

Comment: The Kalman filter as such works absolutely fine. But when I am doing EM and Smoothing, things are not working. I have used a loop which calls the filtering, smoothing and EM till the log-likelihood does not converge. By convergence here I mean the difference between the previous value of log-likelihood and the current is within a threshold level. This is never happening. Will this be a different Question related to programming?

Comment: It could be one of two things . (1) It could be a programming issue (2) It could be an issue of convergence in block models i.e. you are trying multiple blocks of `stuff' in one convergence iteration and these models are not necessarily convergent. In either case it is hard to tell from the details provided. I would recommend starting a new post in this community with your code and exact problem. As a small side note, please be more specific in your next post. When you say `The answer should be negative' it is hard to know what to suggest considering you haven't mentioned the question

Comment: @Sid: I have posted the full code http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142514/matlab-help-needed-in-correcting-the-em-kalman-filter . Could you please help in solving the problem? Shall appreciate your effort and time. Thank you.